# How to pass Rails form params to wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I have this action,

```
  def email_student_report
   @current_year = Time.new.year
   @past_year = @current_year - 1
  end
```

Using this link to,

```
<%= link_to 'Email', samplecardreport_path(format: :pdf), :class => 'btn btn-warning termact_btns' %>
```

I calls this this action and generate a PDF document with wicked_pdf

```
  def sample_card_report
   @subjects = Subject.all
   @properties = Property.first
   @studentid = Student.where('studentid = ?', params[:email_search_stuent_id]).last!
   #@studentid = Student.where('studentid = ?', 'EkGSS-181').last!
   @studentresults = TermReport.where('studentid =? and term =? and form_class =? and year =?', params[:email_search_stuent_id], params[:term], params[:form_class], params[:year])
   @totalstudent = TermReport.group('form_class, term, year, studentid').where('form_class =? and term =? and year =?', params:form_class],params[:term],params[:year],)

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
     render pdf: 'student_report_card',
     template: "term_reports/sample_card_report.pdf.erb"
    end
   end
  end
```

Now my problem is the generated PDF document is blank. And debugging shows that the form params are not being passed so the query is fetching blank. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to send the params manually from the link_to tag using the below mentioned:

```
<%= link_to 'Email', samplecardreport_path(format: :pdf, param1: value1, param2: value2), :class => 'btn btn-warning termact_btns' %>
```

In your case it would be these params

```
<%= link_to 'Email', samplecardreport_path(format: :pdf, email_search_stuent_id: value1, term: value2,form_class: value3, year: value4), :class => 'btn btn-warning termact_btns' %>
```

Also the syntax in this line is also not correct, it is missing [ in form class params

```
@totalstudent = TermReport.group('form_class, term, year, studentid').where('form_class =? and term =? and year =?', params:form_class],params[:term],params[:year],)
```

Correct

```
@totalstudent = TermReport.group('form_class, term, year, studentid').where('form_class = ? and term = ? and year = ?', params[:form_class],params[:term],params[:year],)
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and the suggestions. But it appears you are hardcoding the values. Are you? If not then how are they dynamic?

Comment: No, they are dynamic, the params which you are receiving in the sample_card_report needs to be sent from link_to which is pointing to this action. So need to have the params in link_to page that needs to be sent to sample_card_report.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from your controller to the HTML view you can use the `locals` option in it like this.

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "file_name",   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
        template: "students/pdf.html.erb",
        locals: { data: "hello world"}
      end
    end
```

Then print it in the `views` like this `<%= data %>`